# How to use mono in PHP script?

Tags: php, apache, mono, centos, lamp

Need help:

From terminal my command working fine .
Command:

```
mono Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/first_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/first_XML.xml
```

From php script it's not working on CentOS on server
Command:

```
echo shell_exec('whoami');    
shell_exec('mono Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/fisrt_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/dicentral850_7RRR_XML.xml');
```

Output of :echo shell_exec('whoami');

> on Local: www-data (username)
>
> On Server: icydea5 (username)

Whereas it's working fine in my local setup with Ubuntu OS.

Is it a permission issue?

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. Most likely some issue with your `PATH` environment variable, you might want to try using the absolute path to the `mono` executable. Or maybe system calls are blocked by configuration on that "server".

Comment: whenever i am using 
shell_exec('mono -V'); it's shown version details.
but shell_exec('mono Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/fisrt_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/dicentral850_7RRR_XML.xml'); not working

Comment: So what is the difference between the setup on those two systems? I have no experience with `mono` myself, but certainly it does produce some error output in case something fails? What is that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's **solved**

Steps:

1. Set permission for generating file Directory:'XML_FILES'

   chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t XML_FILES
2. Find mono path command

   which mono
3. set mono path

   shell_exec('/opt/mono/bin/mono Release/X12Parser.exe Release/EDI_FILES/first_edi.edi Release/XML_FILES/first_XML.xml');